# Trace of a Covariance Matrix (OLS vs. Ridge)

Tags: variance, least-squares, ridge-regression, linear-algebra, proof

I am trying to assert that that the trace of the covariance of OLS is more than that of ridge regression to argue why the variance of OLS is more than the variance of ridge:
$$
\frac{1}{n} (X\beta+\varepsilon)'M(X\beta+\varepsilon) = \frac{1}{n} (\varepsilon M \varepsilon'), 
$$
by using that $X'M = MX = 0$ (orthogonality) where $M = I-P$ where $P$ is the projection onto linear space spanned by columns of matrix $X$. Then
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{n} (\varepsilon M \varepsilon')\right] = \frac{1}{n} \text{tr}(\mathbb{E}\left[\varepsilon M \varepsilon'\right],
$$
which can be simplified to $\frac{1}{n} \sigma^2 \mathbb{E}[\text{tr} M]$.

$p = \text{rank} (X)$ eigenvalues = 1. And all other eigenvalues = 0. Trace of a matrix is equal to the sum of its characteristic values, thus $\text{tr}(P)=p$, and $\text{tr}(M) = n − p$.

And hence the expectation is
$$
\mathbb{E}[\sigma ^ 2] = \frac{n-p}{n} \sigma^2.
$$
I am stuck as to how to argue in the same way for ridge regression to assert that the trace of covariance of ridge is smaller than OLS.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I have turned your formulas into LaTeX for better readability. Please check if they are alright. I think you might have misplaced some transposes, but I kept them where you put them. You can of course edit further.